# Применение опций плагина в мобильной версии

Tags: javascript

я установил плагин xzoom. Мне нужно чтобы при переходе в мобильную версию сайта, зум не работал. Там есть опция,которая отключает зум, но применив ее, зум отключается и в полной версии. Опция,которая запрещает зум: mposition:fullscreen.
Вопрос в том, как можно применять эту опцию только для мобильных устройств?

```
$('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({mposition:fullscreen, scroll: false, position: 'lens', lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});
```

Зум применяется для картинок карты товара. html карты я получаю из js файла. В итоге полный код карты:

```
    function goodsOut(data){
    if(data!=0){
        var pack=JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(pack);
        var out="";

    out+='<div class="col-lg-12 single">';
        out+='<div class="col-lg-5 ">';
            out+='<div class="xzoom-container ">';           
                out+=`<img class="xzoom" id="xzoom-default" width="250" xoriginal="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`;
                    out+='<div class="xzoom-thumbs">';
                        out+=`<a href="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`
                            out+=`<img class="xzoom-gallery" width="75"  src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" >`;
                        out+='</a>'
                        out+=`<a href="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`
                            out+=`<img class="xzoom-gallery" width="75"  src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" >`;
                        out+='</a>'
                        out+=`<a href="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`
                            out+=`<img class="xzoom-gallery" width="75"  src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" >`;
                        out+='</a>' 
                    out+='</div>';
            out+='</div>';
 out+='</div>';

        $('.goods-out').html(out);
        $('.ad-to-crt').on('click',addToCart);
        $('.later').on('click',addToLater);
        $('.val-plus').on('click', plusGoods);
        $('.val-min').on('click',minusGoods);


       if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
         $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({ scroll: false, position: 'lens' /*right*/, lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});
        }
    else { 
        $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom(mposition:fullscreen, scroll: false, position: 'lens', lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});
        }
```

Comment: да, можно, вам нужно данный код поместить в обработчик размера экрана, допустим когда ширина экрана <= вашему значению - работает данный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что то напоминающее вот такое:

```js
function goodsOut(data){
    if(data!=0){
        var pack=JSON.parse(data);
        console.log(pack);
        var out="";

    out+='<div class="col-lg-12 single">';
        out+='<div class="col-lg-5 ">';
            out+='<div class="xzoom-container ">';           
                out+=`<img class="xzoom" id="xzoom-default" width="250" xoriginal="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`;
                    out+='<div class="xzoom-thumbs">';
                        out+=`<a href="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`
                            out+=`<img class="xzoom-gallery" width="75"  src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" >`;
                        out+='</a>'
                        out+=`<a href="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`
                            out+=`<img class="xzoom-gallery" width="75"  src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" >`;
                        out+='</a>'
                        out+=`<a href="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}">`
                            out+=`<img class="xzoom-gallery" width="75"  src="pages/orderPage/goods/${pack.img}" >`;
                        out+='</a>' 
                    out+='</div>';
            out+='</div>';
 out+='</div>';
  }
        $('.goods-out').html(out);
        $('.ad-to-crt').on('click',addToCart);
        $('.later').on('click',addToLater);
        $('.val-plus').on('click', plusGoods);
        $('.val-min').on('click',minusGoods);


       if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 360px)').matches) {
         $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({ scroll: false, position: 'lens' /*right*/, lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});
        } else {
        $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({mposition:fullscreen, scroll: false, position: 'lens', lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Я не уверен, но у меня данный код не выдает никаких ошибок... Так же вы пропустили несколько знаков `}` - возможно потому, что это скорее всего не весь код.

Comment: Пишу сначала с условием, после него обычный, с полной версией и все равно почему то зум ни в одной не срабатывает

Comment: ` после него обычный` - что это значит?

Comment: то есть без опции запрета зума

Comment: дополните ответ своим кодом, исправлю свой ответ, если ошибка будет явной

Comment: Такой порядок: `if(window.matchMedia('(max-width: 768px)').matches)
            {
                $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({mposition:fullscreen, scroll: false, position: 'lens', lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});
            }
            
        $('.xzoom, .xzoom-gallery').xzoom({ scroll: false, position: 'lens' /*right*/, lensShape: 'box', bg:true, sourceClass: 'xzoom-hidden'});`

Comment: в консоле выводит,что не находит эту опцию

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос свой код который вы сейчас имеете.

Comment: Добавил,только ваш код немного изменил

Comment: Я не стал весь код выкладывать, поэтому там не все скобки

Comment: @КириллЧетвертков я так и подумал

Comment: В консоле выдает,что не находит эту опцию, но все равно спасибо,что помогли. Я пошел по другому пути: запретил кликать на картинку в мобилке через css